# Как сделать более правильное перемещение

Tags: javascript, математика, pixijs

> http://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/demos/dragging.js

Тут пример, возьмите зайца за край уха и при движении его центр переместится в место клика, а как перетаскивать относительно той позиции за которую зацепил мышью?

Answer (score 2):

Нагуглил, что то сам не догадался, в общем при клике пишем

```
  this.sx = this.data.getLocalPosition(this).x * this.scale.x;
  this.sy = this.data.getLocalPosition(this).y * this.scale.y;
```

Потом при движении

```
  this.x = newPosition.x - this.sx;
  this.y = newPosition.y - this.sy;
```